# How to capture all output of a command which also requires user input from terminal?

Tags: perl

I would like to capture all output (both `STDOUT` and `STDERR`) of a command that also requires user interaction from the terminal window, i.e. it reads `STDIN` and then prints something to `STDOUT`.

Here is minimal version of the script I want to capture the output from:

**user.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter URL: ";
my $ans = <STDIN>;
# do something based on $ans
say "Verification code: AIwquj2VVkwlWEBwway";
say "Access Token: bskjZO8iZotv!";
```

I tried using [`Capture::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) :

**p.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Capture::Tiny qw(tee_merged);

my $output = tee_merged {
    #STDOUT->autoflush(1);  # This does not work
    system "user.pl";
};

if ( $output =~ /Access Token: (.*)$/ ) {
    say $1;
}
```

but it does not work, since the prompt is not displayed until after the user has entered the input in the terminal.

**Edit**:

It seems it works fine if I replace `user.pl` with a python script. For example:

**user.py**:

```python
#! /usr/bin/env python3

ans = input( 'Enter URL: ' )
# do something based on $ans
print( 'Verification code: AIwquj2VVkwlWEBwway' )
print( 'Access Token: bskjZO8iZotv!' )
```

Comment: `system "unbuffer user.pl";` (and possibly `$|=1;` in parent)

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately using `system "unbuffer user.pl"` seems to have some other problems. It displays the prompt correctly, but after typing the input and pressing enter it just hangs, and I have to terminate it with CTRL-C. (I had to install the `unbuffer` command first with `sudo apt-get install expect`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR** There is a solution, it's somewhat ugly, but it works. There are some minor caveats.

**What's going on?** The problem is actually in `user.pl`. The sample `user.pl` that you provided works like this: It starts by printing the string `Enter URL:` to its `stdout`, it then flushes its `stdout` and it then reads a line from its `stdin`. The flushing of the `stdout` occurs automatically by perl: when you try do read from `stdin` with `<..>` (aka `readline`), perl flushes `stdout`. It does that precisely to make programs like this behave correctly. Unfortunately, it appears that perl only implements this behavior when `stdout` is a  tty (pseudo-terminal). If not, it does not flush `stdout` before reading from `stdin`. This is why the script works when you execute it in an interactive terminal session and it doesn't work correctly when you try to capture its output (because in that case its `stdout` is connected to a pipe).

**How to fix this?** Since `user.pl` misbehaves if its `stdout` is not a tty, we must use a tty. AFAIK, [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3A%3ARun) is the only perl module that can capture the output of a subprocess using a tty instead of a plain pipe. Unfortunately, when using a tty, `IPC::Run` does not allow us to redirect `stdout` only, it forces us to redirect `stdin` too. Because of that, we have to handle reading from `stdin` in the parent process on behalf of the child process (yikes!). Here's an example implementation of `p.pl` using `IPC::Run`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Handle;
use IPC::Run;

my $complete_output='';
my $in='';
my $out='';
my $h=IPC::Run::start ['./user.pl'],'<pty<',\$in,'>pty>',\$out;
while ($h->pumpable) {
    $h->pump;
    print $out;
    STDOUT->flush;
    if ($out eq 'Enter URL: ') {
        $in.=<STDIN>;
    }
    $complete_output.=$out;
    $out='';
}
$h->finish;
# do something with $complete_output here
```

So this is somewhat ugly. For example, we try do detect when the subprocess is waiting for user input (by looking for the string `Enter URL:`) and when it does, we read the user input in the parent process and then pass it to the child. Also notice that we have to implement the tee functionality ourselves since `IPC::Run` doesn't offer that.

There are some caveats. The way we handle user input, if the subprocess uses something like the `readline` library to support line editing, this will not work, because we do all the reading in the parent process with a simple `<STDIN>`. Also, because a tty is used behind the scenes instead of a pipe, all user input will be echoed to `stdout`. So whatever the user types in prompt, we put it in `$in` to send it to the process and will get it back from the process (via the `$out` variable). But since our terminal has also echo, the text will appear twice. One solution is filter `$out` to remove the user input and to prevent us from printing it.

Finally, this will not work on Windows.

Comment: @ikegami My answer does exactly what the OP wants. The OP wants to capture the child's output, while letting the user interact with the child process. As I explain, the problem is that because we use a tty, we have to handle reading the `stdin` on behalf of the child. Please read my answer carefully (the 'How to fix it' part). I added a sentence for clarification. If you don't believe me, try it!

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! I was not familiar with the capabilities of `IPC::Run`. I will have to study this in more detail before I can try to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Write your input prompt directly to the tty.

```
open TTY, '>', '/dev/tty';   # or 'con' in Windows
print TTY "Enter URL:";
my $ans = <STDIN>;
...
```

Comment: Nice solution, but in general the script `user.pl` cannot be modified. It must be taken as a black box.